# Issue while getting current date and time from Server in Xcode 6.4

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, nsdate

To avoid any Date and Time issue I planned to get Date from My own `server`.
So I writen this piece of code in a `PHP` file and uploaded that file into my server.

> Date.php

```
<?php

  date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
   $date = date('d/m/Y', time());
    echo $date;

?>
```

Now To access it I am using this piece of code:

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myserver.com/date.php"];
NSError* error;
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

NSDate *serverDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:content];

NSDate *DeviceDate = [NSDate date];
```

> Not the main Root Cause

My system date is set to Current Date and Time. Now when I Debug the Code I am getting:

```
serverDate = 2015-12-27 18:30:00 +0000
```

and

```
deviceDate = 2015-12-28 10:35:16 +0000
```

I am not able to understand why their is one day difference between these two dates. What I am missing?

Comment: there must be miss match between time stamp Like UTC or GMT

Comment: @ismail how can I correct it ?

Comment: i suggest you, while inserting time in database convert date and time  to UTC and insert. And at the user end treat it as UTC and convert it to the local  time zone

Comment: I am not inserting in database...I am just returning it from server.....

Comment: than at the user end ask them to treat it as UTC basically server time will be in UTC if you didnot set it to any other. Other wise you can send the system time zone (Time stamp) to the end user

Comment: once try this ` [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"Asia/Kolkata"]];` since you are using ` date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');' in PHP

Answer (score 1):

Pass both dates in this function. It's returning date in UTC.

```
NSTimeZone *currentTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
NSTimeZone *utcTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];
NSInteger currentGMTOffset = [currentTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:YourDate];
NSInteger gmtOffset = [utcTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:YourDate];
NSTimeInterval gmtInterval = currentGMTOffset - gmtOffset;
NSDate *destinationDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:gmtInterval sinceDate:YourDate] ;
```